# Are Haskell type classes the same thing as Predicate Functor Logic?

Tags: scala, haskell, typeclass

I can't find anything connecting [Quine's Predicate Functor Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_functor_logic) to Computer Science in general.

But I'm somehow convinced type classes are essentially an encoding of predicate functors, especially once you think about how we simulate type classes in Scala...

Comment: What makes you think that PFL is somehow relevant here? Give some examples.

Comment: possibly useful resources: https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2021/03/25/an-introduction-to-typeclass-metaprogramming/ (makes & explins the case that typeclasses are functions from types to terms) and https://aphyr.com/posts/342-typing-the-technical-interview (Prolog-style programming w/ typeclasses)

Comment: The *method* defined by a type class is a function from a type to a term. The type class itself is a mapping of a type to a *constraint* (i.e., a value of kind `Constraint`).

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes,. So, there is so little on PFL directly and I don't know the system well enough, but according to what I could understand a predicate functor is exactly that idea of threading variables (terms) through a predicate that contextualizes it (Constraint), which is also similar to scala's context bounds where the variable is free, but the context bound you have evidence for lets you manipulate it.

Comment: If I go on a limb and start a bunch of handwaving gestures... From this lens you can view the encoding of higher rank types in scala as described in http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/scalagp.pdf as having an unconstrained context bound and just applying the translation from first order logic.to PFL ?

Comment: Maybe I'm just trying to understand PFL...